# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I am currently getting an ArrayDeque class def not found error when testing my app on my phone(version 2.2) however i dont get the error when run in an emulator (2.3.3) 
Heres the Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.ArrayDeque
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ArrayDeque class is added in API level 9 so you can't use it in Android 2.2

Comment: Can it be used if support library is included?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to use Retrofit lib (which uses ArrayDeque and thus I'm getting the same exception on a Froyo devices) in my app which doesn't use ArrayDeque by itself in code. My app has min api lvl 8 so I had to switch to another solution (loopj android async client or aquery) since there is no ArrayDeque support for Froyo.
I realize that Froyo is not an actual AOS version nowadays, however in my newly started app it has over 1% of installs according to Google stats on market, so I don't want to drop its support.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Android's documentation for [`ArrayDeque`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and look at the top right corner, you'll see that it says "Since: API Level 9".

A handy chart for matching the API level to the Android OS version is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). API level 9 is Android 2.3-2.3.2