# Import of class available only in later API permitted?

Tags: android

My project supports API8+. In one method I use an ArrayDeque, which is only available in API9. Therefore it is annotated with "@TargetApi(9)", plus I check the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT before using it.

Now, obviously I have an import java.util.ArrayDeque which throws an error when built against API8. Will it be fine once I built it against the higher targeted API version, but run on a API8-device??

Comment: @pst: "Trying to load a class that does not exist will fail at runtime
 -- not on API Level 5 and higher. Trying to *use* a class that does not exist will fail, but simply referencing it in the source code is fine.

Comment: @pst: Since the OP clearly states "I check the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT before using it", one would assume that the OP is checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` before using it. Since, y'know, that's what the OP wrote. It is also what I emphasize needed to be done in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it be fine once I built it against the higher targeted API version, but run on a API8-device??

Yes, assuming that you are correct about this:

> I check the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT before using it

You would have problems running this on an API Level 4 or lower device, perhaps, as this sort of backwards compatibility was more annoying way back then. But API Level 8 should be fine, so long as you never use this class on devices older than API Level 9.

Comment: "..but *run* on a API8-device??"

Comment: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.ArrayDeque](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197907/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: @PareshMayani, please read the question. I am only USING it on devices API9+...unlike the OP in your linked question.

Comment: Thanks Mark, actually your comment that referencing (and therefore importing it) is fine but using it is not, made it clear.