# NoClassDefFoundError With Choco library

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, choco

I´m trying to run this project made in eclipse with android, and this projects uses the `CHOCO` library. The problem is choco uses a class called `ArraDeque` that gives an error:

> NoClassDefFoundError

If I import this class (`java.util.ArrayDeque`) in any file of mine, eclipse recognizes it, but while the project is running(on an android device) when the choco library is first used the project gives the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I saw many erros related to the `NoClassDefFoundError`, but none of them was involved with a external jar giving the error.

I´ve put some images of the erros [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ounosik5uzwqscw/GnEhBNEp-0).

Comment: Which version of ADT you have?

Comment: I found the answer in another topic, it turns out that array deque is only avaiable in sdk 9 and on, and i was using a device with 8. So... dumb erro after all :/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132532/eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-for-jdk-classes-in-an-android-project

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197907/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror